# Access how do i create a report that shows how many of same including if only 1

Tags: ms-access, report, reporting

I have a db of some 20k error code entries, and i would like to generate a report that show
how many of each is stored.

The user creates a entry when working on a specific error and they get it from another table
example [image]

I tried creating Queries with the selected data for the report and then using the report wizard to help.
but the SUM function add's the codes together, and the count records counts ALL together.

I am looking to create a report that i group by "Area" which is working fine.
and under each area i den count "example from the screenshot" like this

Error:  - >

Do you have any idea's or is there report software that can help me achieve this?

EDIT:
One solution is i found is -
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/count-data-by-using-a-query-b84cdfd8-07ba-49a7-b067-e1024ccfcca8
Count records in a group or category

But then the problem is i am missing a column with the actual reference of the AlarmNo because now i am counting them, and i am still insterested in getting the Original number.

AlarmNo - Count of these.

Comment: I imagine to compare to others it would be similar to count records matching a specific number.

I am thinking
<for each area, count identical (alarmno) records, display how many of each>

Comment: What about `SELECT Area, Count(AlarmCode) FROM Table1 Group By Area` then use this query as report data source.

Comment: Please share your table structure and sample data

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i cannot share data or tables not my data.

Allright i found out what i was doing wrong, it was my sql query.

I changed the queries for each area like this.
This one for England, and it now works when i generate a report.

What i was missing was the  "Count" AS CountOfAlarmCode.
Thank you for looking anyway.

´´SELECT Data2020.[Country], Data2020.[Site], Data2020.[AlarmCode], Count(Data2020.AlarmCode) AS CountOfAlarmCode, Data2020.[AlarmText]
FROM Data2020
GROUP BY Data2020.[Country], Data2020.[Site], Data2020.[AlarmCode], Data2020.[AlarmText]
HAVING (((Data2020.[Country])="England"));´´